# How to download multiple images from url in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Here is code in express.js -

```
    var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('./uploads/streetview/images/' + image_name + '.jpg');
writeStream.on('close', function() {
        console.log('file done');
        });
request(g_url).pipe(writeStream);
```

Its working file for few image urls. But when there are more than 1000, images gets distorted or corrupted.

Comment: you can make client side script , because one request has one response, or you can archeive it

Comment: hi @MuhammadAli thanks for reply. But i can not understand what you said.

Comment: you can do with Client side Javascript , to download all images at one